# keystore file was not created/downloaded

Tags: keystore

when creating a myetherwallet, a keystore file was not created/downloaded and there isn't a private key in my wallet. Also, the system will not print  a paper wallet

Comment: Need screenshots.

Comment: Are you certain you've used the genuine MEW site?